# How to find the time of a sine wave based on the y position?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, programming

I'm trying to find an equation that allows me to find the time of x of the sine wave based on the y position.

For example:

- The y position of 0.25 on the sine wave should equal to 0.0804 in x time
- y0.5 = x0.1667 ((pi/6)/pi)
- y0.75 = x0.2699
- y1 = x0.5

and not to mention the other x values on the other side of the sine in this picture below, if it's possible.

[image]
[image]

I looked everywhere as I can and tried many equations but none of them work and I can't find the equation I'm looking for that would help me get all those x values and more values in between, so I thought I could ask for help because I've been stuck on this math problem for days, thank you.

Comment: Are you just looking for the [inverse function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function) of the sine function? It's called arcsine. See [inverse trigonometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions).

Comment: Thank you @Karl for your comment, I looked into the arcsine like you said, then I went to Desmos and messed around with the function for a bit and I got it working, I can't believe it was that simple. It is (x = arcsine(a) / PI) for the left side and for the other side of the sine it is (x = (1- arcsine(a)) / PI), though another question is it possible to cover both sides of the sine with one equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to post this as an answer, just to leave this for anybody who might have the same trouble. Sorry for the late response; I got preoccupied with something and just kind of forgot about the forum for a good while.

Credit goes to Karl for telling me to use the arcsine in the comments above.

Here's the math and an example for anybody's perusal.

$$\sin(xπ)$$

$$a=amplitude / Y position$$

$$x = \frac{\arcsin(a)}\pi$$

$$x = 1-\frac{\arcsin(a)}\pi$$

[image]